# Remove an older OS from a dual boot OS

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10

I have a laptop running WIndows 8.1 and Windows 10 Dual boot (I Installed Windows 10 last). Both are encrypted with BitLocker.

I want to remove the Windows 8.1 OS, Partition , and remove it from the boot menu.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Removing Windows 8.1 from Boot*

From **Windows 10**, start `MSCONFIG` utitlity. (Use Run box (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>))

Go to `Boot` tag, and remove any unnecessary boot entry from there. If there is only a single entry, while Booting, Windows won't bother showing 30-seconds display to choose boot device.

*Removing Partition*

Use `Disk Management`, Right Click on Computer>Manage>Disk Management, Right Click on Windows 8.1 partition and use `Delete Volume` option.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the ability to choose which OS to boot. Do this in your main OS you want. Now I haven't played with Win10 yet. But in Win 7 & 8 in control panel -> System. Click on Settings button

[image: System Properties]

In "Startup and Recovery" uncheck "Time to display list of OS". Ensure you choose from the drop down list the OS you want to load by default.

[image: Startup and Recovery]

If you use a Partition Manager to reclaim the other partition ensure you backup your HD at the partition level in the event you remove the ability to boot to the OS of your choice and need to recover.

Comment: This just changes the default selection.  He wants to remove the second instance all together including the partition.  Please document how to DO THAT.

Answer (score -2):

Proceed with caution!!
Use GParted and you should be able to delete a partition you don't want, re-size, etc. and fully supports NTFS.  Be sure you have a good backup first. There are other packages that do this, but GParted will require you to use a boot CD to do this.  You will not be able to re-size an in-use partition.

You can edit the menu from Computer Properties to change what partition boots first..

Comment: Thanks. Because both OS's (When loaded) assume they're the C:, even though they're on different partitions, will deleting one cause any issues?

Comment: Why am I being downvoited??  No.  They are not both C: if they are different partitions.You do need to make sure you set the flag of the Primary partition - if not previously set.  Windows will want to run a CHKDSK if you change the geometry of the drive (if you re-size the Windows 10 Partition to be the primary OS of the drive).

Comment: You are being downvoted because you are suggesting a non-Windows solution to a problem that can be easily solved using Windows and it's built in tools/commands. It is also technically incorrect because you **can** resize an in-use partition.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq - I am sorry, but I have to disagree with you.  Maybe I run a bit paranoid when working with computers and is why I recommend using a tool like Gparted as I have been burned by processes like this being in use.  I would rather disconnect the drive, delete, re-size, etc.  A bit "old-school?"  Yes, but I would be a lot more cautious that doing this live.  Yes, I know VMWare and tools like that can add/delete/shrink space while being up and running.

Comment: @Leptonator: You're welcome to disagree, but I have to counter your argument with the exact opposite. G-Parted and the other tools have reverse-engineered and buggy implementations of NTFS. Windows' built-in tools are the only official tools that support all the functionality and are guaranteed not to break anything.